# How can I change the digital clock position so it will be at the top right corner of my website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using weebly.com to edit my site in general i drag object called embed code to a specific page and inside i add a javascript code.
So in my main page i have two javascript codes and they are working fine but they are in the middle of the page one under the second one.

[My Site](http://newsxpressmedia.com/index.html)

And this is the codes for both:

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language='JavaScript'>
$(function(){
 $("ul#ticker01").liScroll();
});
/*!
 * liScroll 1.0
 * Examples and documentation at:
 * http://www.gcmingati.net/wordpress/wp-content/lab/jquery/newsticker/jq-liscroll/scrollanimate.html
 * 2007-2010 Gian Carlo Mingati
 * Version: 1.0.2.1 (22-APRIL-2011)
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses:
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 * http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
 * Requires:
 * jQuery v1.2.x or later
 *
 */


jQuery.fn.liScroll = function(settings) {
  settings = jQuery.extend({
  travelocity: 0.10
  }, settings);  
  return this.each(function(){
    var $strip = jQuery(this);
    $strip.addClass("newsticker")
    var stripWidth = 1;
    $strip.find("li").each(function(i){
    stripWidth += jQuery(this, i).outerWidth(true); // thanks to Michael Haszprunar and Fabien Volpi
    });
    var $mask = $strip.wrap("<div class='mask'></div>");
    var $tickercontainer = $strip.parent().wrap("<div class='tickercontainer'></div>");        
    var containerWidth = $strip.parent().parent().width(); //a.k.a. 'mask' width  
    $strip.width(stripWidth);   
    var totalTravel = stripWidth+containerWidth;
    var defTiming = totalTravel/settings.travelocity; // thanks to Scott Waye  
    function scrollnews(spazio, tempo){
    $strip.animate({left: '-='+ spazio}, tempo, "linear", function(){$strip.css("left", containerWidth); scrollnews(totalTravel, defTiming);});
    }
    scrollnews(totalTravel, defTiming);    
    $strip.hover(function(){
    jQuery(this).stop();
    },
    function(){
    var offset = jQuery(this).offset();
    var residualSpace = offset.left + stripWidth;
    var residualTime = residualSpace/settings.travelocity;
    scrollnews(residualSpace, residualTime);
    });   
  }); 
};
</script>

<style>
/* liScroll styles */

.tickercontainer { /* the outer div with the black border */
border: 1px solid #000;
background: #fff;
width: 500px;
height: 27px;
margin: auto 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
}
.tickercontainer .mask { /* that serves as a mask. so you get a sort of padding both left and right */
position: relative;
left: 10px;
top: 8px;
width: 500px;
overflow: hidden;
}
ul.newsticker { /* that's your list */
position: relative;
left: 500px;
font: bold 10px Verdana;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;

}
ul.newsticker li {
float: left; /* important: display inline gives incorrect results when you check for elem's width */
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background: #fff;
}
ul.newsticker a {
white-space: nowrap;
padding: 0;
color: #ff0000;
font: bold 10px Verdana;
margin: 0 50px 0 0;
}
ul.newsticker span {
margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}
</style>

<ul id="ticker01">
 <li><span>10/10/2007</span><a href="#">The first thing ...</a></li>
 <li><span>10/10/2007</span><a href="#">End up doing is ...</a></li>
 <li><span>10/10/2007</span><a href="#">The code that you ...</a></li>
 <!-- eccetera -->
</ul>


<div id="clock" class="dark">
    <div class="display">
        <div class="weekdays"></div>
        <div class="ampm"></div>
        <div class="alarm"></div>
        <div class="digits"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.0.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/theme/digiclock.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/theme/digiclock.css">
```

The code for the digital clock is in the bottom:

```
<div id="clock" class="dark">
        <div class="display">
            <div class="weekdays"></div>
            <div class="ampm"></div>
            <div class="alarm"></div>
            <div class="digits"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.0.0/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/theme/digiclock.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/theme/digiclock.css">
```

My question how can i change it's position ? Is it in the javascript code or should be something with weebly.com editor i'm using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Add:

`style="position:absolute;top:0px;right:0px;"`

To `Div` with `id="clock"`

That Means,

Change The Line: `<div id="clock" class="dark">`

with this: `<div id="clock" class="dark" style="position:absolute;top:0px;right:0px;">`

or in your `css` file add:

```
#clock
{
position:absolute;
top:0px;
right:0px;
}
```

And here is Output:
[image: Output Of My Code]

Hope It Helps You!! Cheers!  :)..